# frequency of netlink messages

Tags: c++, linux, netlink

I am using the inet_diag module and libpcap to get the uid of the user who accessed the url I captured using libpcap. As there may be many urls captured per second, I was wondering if there was a limit to how many netlink msgs should be sent per second, and if I should cache and occasionally refresh, or blithely send a msg every time a url is captured.

Comment: What if the socket that the URL string was being transmitted over is already closed by the time you send off the NL inquiry message?

Comment: I don't think that scenario will be common, but I don't really see how your comment applies.

Comment: Such a limit would be artifical - no real reason to have it. Just send as many as you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please add your comment as an answer so that 1) I can accept it, and 2) others can find it better. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a limit would be artifical - no real reason to have it. Just send as many as you need.